# Error while running the react native maps app

Tags: react-native

[image]

My code:App.js

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import CurrentPosition from './currentPosition'
import Tracker from './watchPosition'

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Mapview style={styles.map}
        region={{
          latitude:59.329,
          longitude:18.068,
          latitudeDelta:0.1,
          longitudeDelta:0.1
                }}
                >
                </Mapview>
        <Tracker />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position:'absolute',
    top:0,
    left:0,
    bottom:0,
    right:0,
    justifyContent:'flex-end',
    alignItems:'center'
  },
  map:{
     position:'absolute',
      top:0,
    left:0,
    bottom:0,
    right:0
  }
});
```

The values are hard coded for latitude and longitude for test purposes. Although when I try to run the app the following error persists shown in the image provided

Error:
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

go to `./node_modules/react-native-maps/build.gradle`
then do this:

```
implematition -> compile
compileOnly -> provided
```

Comment: change the implematition to compile and also compileOnly to provided

Comment: But the implementation and compileOnly options are not there in the build.gradle file by default. So Do I need to add anything?